# selector drawable showing corner radius only in not_night mode but showing border in the night mode

Tags: android, xml, background, themes, drawable

Here are the images of android studio not_night mode and night mode respectively.
[image: not_night]

[image: night]

Code for the selector drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>

    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="16dp" android:topRightRadius="16dp" />

    </shape>

</item>
```

Code for the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Motion3Activity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/main_container"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/main_container"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/main_container"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_title"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/mountain" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_desc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/main_container"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/main_container"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/main_container" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras porttitor ultricies leo mi amet. Ut enim in ac egestas dolor. Lectus sociis dolor lectus elit semper habitant egestas gravida. Feugiat in morbi tempor, diam nibh sem odio neque ac. Nunc commodo in et ac ut pharetra, convallis ipsum. Dui facilisi consectetur diam tortor. In ultricies nunc laoreet dictumst velit purus sed." />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/top_round_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_desc"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/main_container"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/main_container">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="Himalaya"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

now When I run my code and my device is in dark mode the corner border is visible but in the case of light mode, the corner border is not there.

I want the top left and right corners of the linear layout to be curved.

Comment: do you create any resource night mode variant in `res/` directory?

Comment: Yes in style.xml i made 2 styles one light and another dark.

Comment: This might be rhe case.. Can you share them or disable the dark one for a while

Comment: https://github.com/plazzy99/GitFit/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml
this is the code for the style